# Is enthalpy of activation the same as activation energy? Is there a purely mathematical way to find that value?

Tags: physical-chemistry, enthalpy, entropy, reaction-control

I asked about the effect of pressure on a reaction, and since then I learned a lot more. One of the things I learned was the Eyring equation:

$$\kappa = \frac{\kappa_B T}{h} e^\frac{\Delta^\ddagger S°}{R} e^\frac{- \Delta^\ddagger H°}{R}$$

where:

$\begin{multline}
\begin{split}
\kappa &= \text{reaction rate} \\
\kappa_B &= \text{Boltzmann constant} \\
T &= \text{temperature} \\
h &= \text{Planck's constant} \\
R &= \text{gas constant} \\
\Delta^\ddagger S° &= \text{entropy of activation} \\
\Delta^\ddagger H° &= \text{enthalpy of activation} \\
\end{split}
\end{multline}$

My questions:

1. Is the enthalpy of activation the same thing as the activation
   energy?
2. Is there a purely mathematical way to determine both $\Delta^\ddagger S°$ and $\Delta^\ddagger H°$? (without having a laboratory to use to observe the reaction)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) `Enthalpy` of activation is a component of `activation energy`. The other component is `temperature * entropy` of activation. Enthropy controls "heat difference" while entropy controls "measure of disorder difference".

$\Delta$G = $\Delta$H - T*$\Delta$S. This applies to activation energy too.

(2) DFT functionals rely on 4 parameters per atom make predictions. So, if you give 4*5=20 parameters, then you can in theory predict behaviour of any compound, build with only C, H, N, O, S atoms. This covers most of biochemistry, excluding nucleic acids (you would need additional 4 parameters to characterize P).

These 4 parameters are known for most of the atoms (excluding some elements, going after uranium). But those four parameters were experimentally measured by fitting behavior of modeled molecules to real molecules.

Should we count it as "purely theoretically predict?"

Also there are purely *ab* *initio* methods like Hartree-Fock with even less input required. You would still need some input. In math you can build many different plausible worlds. For example purely "newtonian" vs "newtonian + quantum mechanics" words. experiment is the only way to tell, which model is correct.

Comment: Wow, I downloaded JDFTx and it is way beyond my understanding. Do you have an idea of something easier to use?

Comment: In my PhD QM 30% of work was relevant to QM. I am now working as a coder.  JDFTx is above my head. It is a "plugin" (one of the DFT potentials) to work with a very specific case "calculations of electronic systems in contact with liquid environments". It is not a mainstream approach so you might not find tutorials.

Comment: Feasible steps for you would be (1) ACD/ChemSketch to draw molecules -> (2)  convert to 3D (in ChemSketch) -> (3) use Gaussian to compute properties. If you try to build Minecraft level from ab initio QM, it will not work. Currently professors in computational chemistry develop methods to model protein-protein interaction. A computational model of a whole cell is a dream in the field. The problem isn't that they can't find solutions to the equations. The problem is that using modern supercomputers you would use a billion years to model a nanosecond of life of a single cell.

Comment: Licensed Gaussian costs money, but it is a de-facto standard. You can check alternatives here https://www.reddit.com/r/chemistry/comments/s6m0w/opensource_gaussian_alternative/, but I've never worked with those.

Comment: All that just to predict entropy and enthalpy of activation of a reaction?

Comment: Try to find Gaussian software and see some tutorials on how to use it. This would be a good start.

Comment: @sixtytrees Are you claiming that by computational means alone you can accurately calculate the properties of transition states?

Comment: @porphyrin Yes, you can. TS for small molecules work well. CF3 substituent slowed a reaction I was working on by a factor of 500 (measured) 450-470 (computed at DFT(B3LYP)/6-31++ depending on solvent model). This agreement is good given simplicity of B3LYP.  I could have used a better solvation model, but this accuracy was sufficient for my purposes. It is indeed hard to predict KIE for enzymatic reaction when tunneling effects become significant. We can always tweak the functional to give us results we need for a small set of reactions, but we don't have a robust method for all cases.

Comment: I don't know the technical terms, all I want is to be able to know the values of enthalpy and entropy of activaton of a given reaction. Are those values properties of the reaction, meaning are they constant? If so, the rate of the reaction can be calculated as a function of T. Or, maybe enthalpy and entropy of activation are not constant for a given reaction, but vary as temperature and pressure vary? maybe enthalpy is a function of the reaction equation and temperature, and entropy a function of the reaction equation and pressure? I just guessing so you guys can see what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm not talking about proteins or anything that complex, maybe homopolymers as polyethylene, I don't need enzimes or any of that, just simple reactions between simple compounds, like Ca(OH)2 + K2CO3 → CaCO3 + 2 KOH

Comment: By the way, Gaussian is paid aand extremely expensive (like $ 6,000 a license). I found this other one called Orca (license is free), I wanted to see if you ever heard of it, and, if yes, if it can do what I need.

Comment: "Ca(OH)2 + K2CO3 → CaCO3 + 2 KOH".  You would think this exchange is simple. It is actually very complex. You have to account for formation of bulk phase (precipitate). First of all it is bulk (so you need a lot of atoms in your model. Second, you need solvent molecules. Third, you need a decent model of a crystal.Trying to predict which crystal lattice will form in precipitation of CaCO3 is already a state of art computation. The easiest thing to model is the reaction of CH3Cl with CN-. Ideally it should have two molecules one of which is neutral and the other is charged.

Comment: Gaussian wants money. Someone in internet might share a "free copy" with you. For your purposes you should Gamess or Orca are a good start. I haven't use either of them, but heard good words about Gamess. You should open a separate question about QM modelling so that we stay on topic. There we can discuss models that you should start with, methods you can use and so on. Btw, even modelling liquid water is difficult. Water model (there are many things you can compare with experiment) is a first benchmark of the quality of your QM model.

Comment: I don't know what the title of the question should be (this is how lost I am at this point. I will get it all together eventually, but right now I'm totally lost). Any suggestions? I don't want to make a question with a bad title. Even though this forum is much friendlier and less strict (more chill) than stackoverflow, I don't want to show lack of effort.

Comment: @sixtytrees about what you said of the reaction between calcium hydroxide and potassium carbonate, is all that necessary to determine the enthalpy of activation and the entropy of activation. What I want is the following: given a reaction equation, a temperature and a pressure, what fraction of each reactant (in moles) will participate in the reaction and what will be the fraction of products (in moles) obtained. And then be able to tweak temperature and pressure to achieve a 100% reaction, where all reactants react to form the products.

Comment: @FinnTheHuman "What makes a reaction an easy or a difficult target for computational modeling?" start with a question like this.

Comment: @sixtytrees I have no idea

Comment: I am saying that is a good title for your new question.